# ClickOnce sometimes adding more than one shortcut to Start Menu?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce deployment for my application (Fredster).  It gets installed per user on a server that each user logs into.  Sometimes/somehow, the Start menu begins adding Fredster -1, Fredster -2, etc.  I assume this is only a shortcut, the app seems to run fine no matter which icon in the Start Menu is clicked for any user.  But why is this happening, and how do i keep it from adding these confusing "shortcuts"?  It doesn't ever happen when i install the app locally.

Comment: The shortcut name is incremented each time it is already in the start menu. So if the setup wants to add another short for the installation, but the shortcut "Fredster -1" already exists, it creates "Fredster -2".

Comment: How/Why is the shortcut getting incremented though?  When the app updates, it shouldn't try to put ANOTHER shortcut in.  Also, if different users install through ClickOnce, it shouldn't do that.  I noticed Uninstall does not remove the folder that contains it, is there a way to remove the Startup entry as well?

Comment: It is incremented because it already exists. If there's no shortcut from you app at all, it will create "Fredster". Yes it shouldn't create another one, but if the deployment identity is different, it will (just look, if you have 2 entries in the programs & features list)(also: take a look at side-by-side deployment). Well, the folder should stay - it's the start menu folder :)
And sure: You can browse (either manually or by code) the start menu folder and delete the file.

Comment: and what causes the deployment identity to be different?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Altought I cannot reproduce, but the client does. Have you solved it?

Comment: not really, but it isn't occurring anymore.  after i had them uninstall all instances etc.  i guess further changes haven't been "different" enough to have this problem occur...

Comment: Is there an option to overwrite the initial shortcut without creating duplicates with "-1", "-2" at the end of the name?